# How to create a PowerBI gauge displaying data for the current month?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to create a gauge element that would always display values ***for the current month.*** I can create the elements and manually select for example 2/2016 but I would like it to just always display data for the current month (i.e. 3/2016 next month).

I can create a measure to retrieve the MaxDate but i cannot use that in a slicer of figure out how I could use the data with filters etc.

Any ideas on how this kind of logic could be implement it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use the Power BI Desktop to edit your data model as follows:
1) create a DAX Measure 
2) Use the Calculate function to calculate your data point.
3) In your Calculate set a filter so that the MonthYear
4) Use that new measure in your guage

You will also want to create new measures for:
A) Target value
B) Max value

These you'll wire into your gauge so that you don't get the annoying - my gauge is always at the 50% mark issue :).

Some useful references you might want to consult:
https://wouterbasson.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/filtering-the-current-period-using-dax/
http://www.daxpatterns.com/

Comment: Thanks that solved my it perfectly!  It took a little digging on how to correctly formulate the measure so here's an little example for anyone interested:
1. Measure  : mySum = SUM(valueX)
2. Measure :  mySumForCurrentMonth = CALCULATE( [mySum ];  [MonthYear] = FORMAT(NOW(); "MM/YYYY"))